# joomla to wordpress migration and 404 errors issues

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I had migrated my website from Joomla to WordPress with "FG Joomla to WordPress premium"

the problem is that I have more than 2900 posts in my website they all are now imported in WordPress version but images in my posts are linked like this:
example.com/postname/articles/image.jpg
but in WordPress images should be like :
example.com/wp-content/image.jpg
now I all my 2900 posts images are broken and not shown.
I decided to redirect it but I don't know how to that cause it's variable post names !!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend an extension called RegularLabs DB Replacer.  The free version should do what you need.  Just go to the com_content table where Joomla stores the articles, and in the introtext and fulltext fields and you can do the find and replace there.  I also recommend switching the image src= to relative paths instead of absolute paths that contain your domain name in them.

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/dbreplacer

Comment: thanks for your reply and excuse me for my mistake in the title. currently, I use Wordpress and I migrated from Joomla to Wordpress so I need a WP plugin to do that.